# CrossTextToSpeech sound issue in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have created a .NET 2017 solution to start a Text To Speech app. I have followed online instructions and seems really simple, I added the TextToSpeech plugin version 3.0.1 to the solution and added the following code to the MainPage of the Portable Project:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinTextToSpeech"
                 x:Class="XamarinTextToSpeech.MainPage">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry x:Name="Enter" />
                <Button Text="Speak" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Plugin.TextToSpeech;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinTextToSpeech
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var text = Enter.Text;
            CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak(text);

        }
    }
}
```

But when I debug to an Android emulator (VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone) and type in something to the Entry textbox, there is no sound. I have stepped through the code and the entered text definitely gets passed in.

Have I missed something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the language package installed on your emulator (use the recommended command `GetInstalledLanguages()` to check it out)? Did you try it on a real device? It looks ok to me

Comment: thank you Diego, I installed it on an actual android device and it didn't make any difference. I will try GetInstalledLanguages() though. cheers